# Why are the coordinates in game engines inverse?

Tags: math, game-engine, coordinate-systems

Real coordinate system (most used and taught to most of us)

```
(0,3)-(1,3)-(2,3)
(0,2)-(1,2)-(2,2)
(0,1)-(1,1)-(2,1)
(0,0)-(1,0)-(2,0)
```

coordinate system used by game engines

```
(0,0)-(1,0)-(2,0)
(0,1)-(1,1)-(2,1)
(0,2)-(1,2)-(2,2)
(0,3)-(1,3)-(2,3)
```

Comment: Mostly because frame buffers (i.e. the memory that stores the current image) is layed out in increasing memory address order from left to right and top to bottom, which in turn probably originates from the fact that that's the order in which old CRT monitors "draw" their content.

Comment: Also note that basically *all* graphics on computers uses the top left as the 0,0 coordinate, not just game engines.